# MvvmCross open page and navigate to detail view directly

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a page with a list, `ListViewModel` and of each list item, there is a detail view, `DetailViewModel`.

Now I want to navigate from `AnotherViewModel` to the list page and open directly one of the detail views.

I don't want to open `DetailViewModel` directly from `AnotherViewModel`, because the user should get to `ListViewModel` when pressing the back-button.

For this purpose, I call in my `AnotherViewModel`:

```
this.ShowViewModel<ListViewModel>(new { showDetailId = "42" });
```

In `ListViewModel` I have my init-method like this:

```
public void Init(string showDetailId)
{
    this.LoadList();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(showDetailId))
    {
        this.ShowViewModel<DetailViewModel>(new { detailid = showDetailId });
    }
}
```

This works perfectly in Android, but in iOS, the views get somehow messed up: I see the ListView, but also the "< Back" button. Clicking the "< Back", the app hangs.

I would expect to see the DetailView and the "< Back" which should lead back to the ListView.

Comment: It might be easier to navigate to the detail view, handle back button, and navigate forward to the list view.  You can manipulate the stack in a presenter so it appears to work by just going back.

Comment: A custom presenter, a delayed navigation call or a switch somewhere in the calling code is definitely a better way to go here - showing a ViewModel from Init causes reentrant presentation/navigation calls - which can cause UI issues on iOS and on Windows too.